# Different SSH login with subdomain on same IP

Tags: ssh, subdomain

I'm in the following situation: I own a domain pointing on my local network (NAT), let's call it domain.ch. I have set a subdomain sub.domain.ch pointing on the same IP as domain.ch.

What I would like would be that `ssh user@domain.ch` chroots to somewhere else than `ssh user@sub.domain.ch` with the user being the same both time. The effect would be to emulate two different machines.

What I thought for a solution would be to redirect sub.domain.ch:22 to some other port, and then to listen to it with ssh, but I don't even know how to do it easily, and there may be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

The SSH handshake consist of version exchange, key exchange and Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman (ECDH) initialization. Unlike the SNI in TLS or `Host` in HTTP, these steps with SSH handshake doesn't involve hostnames.

There's simply nothing to distinguish `sub.example.com` from `example.com`; after getting the IP address from DNS the IP address alone is used for establishing the connection. You would have to use a different IP address or a different TCP port.

Answer (score 0):

When using SSH, the the domain name is converted to an IP address, and can't be used for "switching" on by the client - so if this needs to happen on the server side, you can't do it.   (In addition to @esajokinen correct partial answer, SSH also dies not use srv records).

On the client side, however, there are possible solutions.  Openssh, for example, has fairly robust configuration options which DO work on a hostname basis. If specifying different settings client side is appropriate, there are options - including (rather complex to set up) working with SSH bound to 2  different ports. Your .SSH/cinfig file might look like

```
  Host subdomain.ch
       Port 2222
```

To connect you to port 2222 rather then 22.

But there are lots of easier examples -  like specifying different usernames, key pairs or, most valuably ProxyCommand parameters. ProxyCommand let's you specify an arbitrary command to run, so if your user is root equivalent, you could tell it to execute a chroot command to restrict the SSH environment visible.

None of this is solid from a security POV however, and I also wonder if you misunderstand SSH - SSH is a highly flexible protocol to allow systems to talk to each other, but AFAIK it has no concept if chroot/jails. Restrictions are controlled by the OS and user permissions.

Comment: Well, if there is no domain header contained in SSH packets, there is indeed no hope. Chroot there isn't for security, just for convenience, to clean up what users see. I mainly use ssh for git and sftp, and I need to host different sftp and git servers on the same machine, and I don't really know how. Any idea?